# Python Pandas Drop Consecutive Data Frames but Period (.) at the End is the Differentiator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

Hi I have a section of my pandas dataframe that has duplicates, but the difference is minor.

The only differentiator is a period at the end.

| Header A |
| --- |
| First |
| First. |

I just want to drop the row that has a duplicate that does not have a period.

Comment: I add new data sample to my answer, what is expcted ouput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sorting by `Header A`, then remove last `.` and get last duplicated values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
print (df)
  Header A
0   First.
1    First
2   First.
3  Second.
4   Second
5    Third
6    Third


df1 = df.sort_values('Header A')
df1 = df1[~df1['Header A'].str.rstrip('.').duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df1)
  Header A
2   First.
3  Second.
6    Third
```

If need prioritize values without `.`:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('Header A')
df2 = df1[~df1['Header A'].str.rstrip('.').duplicated()]
print (df2)
  Header A
1    First
4   Second
5    Third
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try `loc`:

```
>>> x = df['Header A'].str.split('.', expand=True)
>>> df.loc[x[0].duplicated(keep=False) & x[1].isna()]
  Header A
0    First
>>>
```

Comment: But OP need `I just want to drop the row that has a duplicate that does not have a period.`

Comment: @jezrael Yes this does that :)